# Can I go to a specific section in a google form with a pre-filled URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a Google Form with 6 sections (pages).  The answer to the question in the first section goes to sections 2, 3, 4, or 5 based on the answer.  Then, the final section (section 6) is answered by all.  As a shortcut, I have generated pre-filled URLs with answers to Section 1 and then the corresponding other section (2,3,4,or 5).  I am creating QR codes so people can scan from their device.  I'd like the QR code URL to go straight to Section 6 with the pre-filled values for the earlier sections.  Unfortunately, the pre-filled URL Google Forms generates goes to section 1 and the user could theoretically change the values and has 2 unnecessary steps.

I do want to maintain the option to fill out the first sections in the form, as sometimes people access this form without access to the QR code with the pre-filled sections complete.

Any ideas on how to get the pre-filled url to go straight to section 6 and skip the first two steps?

I looked into triggers for the form to see if I could write a script to go to page, but all of the simple triggers require users to have edit access to the form.  I don't see any triggers for opening a form to submit responses.

I also tried this: https://bionicteaching.com/silent-submission-of-google-forms/ 
I was hoping it attempt to submit the form but kick back to section 6 as that question response is flagged as "required" and it is blank.  Unfortunately, that didn't work, it submitted the form without the required response.  :(